# Swift not able to interact with page even though on separate thread

Tags: swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I am new to using separate threads. I think I did this wrong. I am trying to have this animation happen but allow the user to interact with the page while its happening.

Here is my code

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            self.backgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        })

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.backgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        }
    }
```

Comment: Animations must take place on the main thread. If you want to allow user interaction, use the `.AllowUserInteraction` option in `animationWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completions:`.

Comment: Thank you! worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Rob for the answer.

> Animations must take place on the main thread. If you want to allow user interaction, use the .AllowUserInteraction option in animationWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completions